# JavaScript object - numeric key literal undefined

Tags: javascript, object-literal

This snippet of code has the values I list in the comments.

```
var studentid = course.roster[i];     // studentid = 1367
console.log(studentid);               // prints 1367
console.log(students[1367]);          // correctly prints a student object
```

If I change the key in the third line to use a variable with the exact same value, then the result is undefined. Why?

```
console.log(students[studentid]);     // fails to print correctly
```

This is the output from `console.log(students[1367])`:

```
Object {
    lname: "John",
    fname: "Smith",
    grade: "Sophomore",
    id: "1367",
    email: "jsmith@domain.com"
}
```

This is the output from `console.log(students[studentid])`:

```
undefined
```

Comment: may be `studentid` is return string

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
var studentid = course.roster[i];     // studentid = 1367
```

its return string and your `id`  in `integer` so try to convert the studentid into string

```
var studentid = parseInt(course.roster[i]);     // studentid = 1367
```

which will work in your case

Answer (score 0):

try to parse the string id to number.

`console.log(students[Number(studentid)]);`